# Is Ubuntu LTS running a DEBUG kernel?

Tags: kernel, debug

I found this in my system log:

```
[   14.845195] **********************************************************
[   14.845196] **   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
[   14.845196] **                                                      **
[   14.845196] ** trace_printk() being used. Allocating extra memory.  **
[   14.845197] **                                                      **
[   14.845197] ** This means that this is a DEBUG kernel and it is     **
[   14.845197] ** unsafe for production use.                           **
[   14.845197] **                                                      **
[   14.845198] ** If you see this message and you are not debugging    **
[   14.845198] ** the kernel, report this immediately to your vendor!  **
[   14.845198] **                                                      **
[   14.845198] **   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
[   14.845199] **********************************************************
```

It is labelled **"unsafe for production."**

But I got my kernel from the LTS repository:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntupc 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is from **linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic** (4.15.0-66.75)

Why did a debug kernel end up in Ubuntu's repository?

OS: **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**

Video Driver: **nvidia-driver-440**

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep terminator`  maybe https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1786467

Comment: The terminator grep gives nothing. I did tag myself on that bug entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the trace_printk() **was not in the kernel** itself, but in a (proprietary) **module**.

In my case, the **sep5.ko** module was responsible for this kernel notice, and this module is part of the [Intel VTune Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune) suite.

The vtune software had nested itself in `/etc/rc0.d/K01sep5` and `/etc/rc0.d/K01sep4_1` and after removing those, the kernel notice disappeared.